# Instagram Basic Api Android Emulator

Tags: android, ios, flutter, chromium, instagram-api

Instagram basic display api doesnt authenticate on Android. But it works on Ios emulator.

I am using flutter_webview_plugin 0.4.0 package. It gives me an error above.

```
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'bluetooth'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'hid'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'local-fonts'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'otp-credentials'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'serial'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'usb'.", source:  (0)
I/chromium(27494): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy-Report-Only header: Unrecognized feature: 'xr-spatial-tracking'.", source:  (0)
```

And sometimes it's working on Postman but sometimes it doesnt work. It gives 400 error. And the message is "You must provide a valid client id and code". But it's always works on ios simulator. Is there anyone experiencing this situation?